# Regulator of a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I’m trying to understand the claim that a regulator measures the density of the group of units. In particular, on Wikipedia they say that if the regulator is small, then there are “lots” of units. I don’t see how this is true. The regulator is the volume of a certain lattice spanned by the fundamental units of the group of units. In particular, it feels like a bigger volume would imply the existence of more units. Or in other words, more units mean that a bigger area is covered by the units. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: It is the volume of the largest (open) parallelogram without units.

Comment: Of $L_1 = \mathbb Z e_1 \oplus \mathbb Z e_2$ and $L_2 = 2\mathbb Z e_1 \oplus 2\mathbb Z e_2$, both considered as lattices in $\mathbb R^2$, which has the fundamental region with greater volume? Visually, which of them is more "dense" in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Ofcourse, I shouldn’t see it as the volume of the lattice but actually as the volume of the corresponding fundamental domain, which is indeed the largest parallelogram without units. And then indeed a bigger fundamental domain means less denser units.

Comment: Maybe this is also the reason why people often call it a co-volume of the lattice.